# .MP4 is not playing in IOS

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, html, safari, mp4

I have a ".mp4" video on my web page within video tag as below.

```
    <video class="video-content" controls="controls" poster="/poster.jpg" width="840" tabindex="-1" >
        <source src="/ket.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
        <track kind="subtitles" label="English subtitles" src="/ket.vtt" srclang="en"></track>
        Your browser doesn&#39;t support HTML5 video tag.
    </video>
```

This is working well in all the browser and devices **EXCEPT** IOS (safari, iPhone, iPad)

In Safari developer tools, under the "Network" tab, when I check the details for the "ket.mp4":

**Under the "Preview" tab:**

An error occurred trying to load the resource

**Under the "Headers" tab:**

**Summary:**

Status: 200 OK

Source: Network

**Request**

Range: bytes=0-1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) 
AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1 Safari/605.1.15
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: identity
Referer: https://www.example.com/ket.htm
X-Playback-Session-Id: 9C7F2AF7-9747-4AAD-B82D-A3D133FE4B20

**Response**

Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 17142979
Date: Thu, 31 May 2018 10:55:38 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 10 May 2018 17:32:50 GMT
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: public, max-age=633

When I see the status, request, and response. I understand the server is responding to the request with the status 200. so, there should not be an issue on the server front. Because, i see the "content-length" under the "response" tab with its value as well.

when I check the forums, I see some discussion going around the "controls" attribute to set "true" or "false" or "controls". in my case I am setting controls attribute value as controls only.

Note: when I hit the ".mp4" URL directly in the browser, the video not playing and getting the same request/response in the developer tools.

Does anyone have any idea on this? how to make it this video works in Safari/iPhone/IPad. Do I need to understand this issue is on ".mp4" file itself? or Browser specific? or anything inside the "IIS Server".

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

I am not necessarily sure if it would be the issue, but it does fit the bill. Make sure that the audio codec is compatible with iOS. I faced a similar issue where I was receiving videos that had HECV as the audio codec, switching them to H.264 fixed the issue.